# Flex - Passing request data with URL fragments

Tags: apache-flex, iis

I'm passing the following parameter as an url fragment to flex. (#groupID=2385)

This works great on the development box, but when I put it on the production server.. nothing.

Do you think this is a server configuration issue. I presume that flex is talking to the javascript file 'AC_OETags.js' to make this all happen.

Any pointers much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to "history.js", "history.css", and "historyFRame.html" on release? They should be packed into your release folder as well as the AC_OETags.js if you're using the browser history in flex.

Comment: No, flex builder doesn't seem to be outputting those files when I do a release build. I'll check it out. Thanks.